# deformation space inside cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

For which smooth projective varieties $X$ is $H^1(X,T_X)$ (canonically ) contained in $H^\cdot(X,\mathbb C)$?

If $K_X$ is trivial this is true. But are there other type of varieties?